# Prevent running other vba projects when open workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I opened two workbooks (A,B) containing vba codes in Excel 2016.

When I run macro (workbooks.open) in A,
macro in B runs automatically.

I don't want to run macro in B.

How can I prevent running macros in B?

Comment: Add `Application.EnableEvents = False` as your first line in your `Workbooks.Open` in A. Remember to turn it back on after.

Comment: Thank you for comments. I try "Application.EnableEvents = False", but it does not work.

Comment: We wan't help you if you don't show your code. Please [edit] your question and add the code of the `workbooks.open` event. Also add the information of **which** macro *"macro in B runs automatically"* this is that runs automatically. Finally if you say *"I opened two workbooks (A,B)"* how did you open them? By VBA code? If so show that code too.